# I need help for my website. How to fix the <a href=""></a>

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When I click the `<a href="name.php"></a>` it is automatically reloading. That is my problem. I want to stay in the page when I do updating data. Kindly help me how to fix it.

```
<li class="has-sub">
   <a href="#studentinformation">
      <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Student Information <span class="sub-arrow"></span>
   </a> 
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Basic Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">School</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Example, when I click the "Basic Information", it will automatically reload. This code is located at my sidebar then the "Basic Information, Contact Information and School" are the dropdown data.

Comment: that is "the <a href=""></a>" it is....

Comment: Share some code. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. We need a [mcve] of what you have now along with what your end goal is.

Comment: There is nothing to fix. A click on a link _should_ reload. What you might want to get is a SPA (SinglePageApplication). You'll need some ajax and or a SPA-Framework for that.

Comment: `<li class="has-sub"><a href="#studentinformation"><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i> Student Information <span class="sub-arrow"></span></a>

<ul>
<li><a href="#">Basic Information</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Contact Information</a></li>
<li><a href="#">School</a></li>     
</ul>

</li>`

Example, when I click the "Basic Information", it will automatically reload. 

This code is located at my sidebar then the "Basic Information, Contact Information and School" are the dropdown data.

Comment: What else should happen when you click on 'Basic Information'?

Comment: It appear table information. Sorry I don't know how to put image here cos I'm a newbie. After that, it will automatically refresh when I click the Basic Information Link. I want to Stay open the dropdown menu part.

Comment: ajax, Single Page Application. Search for that after you've walked trough some basic tutorials on web programming!

Comment: What @Jeff means is that you'll have to code some Javascript to handle the click event on the web browser to control this behaviour

Comment: What should I do? I need this for our thesis. :'(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:;">...</a>
```